# How to get product QTY on product view page?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, qty

I'm trying to get the quantity of the products in this file below, using **$_product->getQty()** but doesn't get, is returned NULL.

```
design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

Answer (score 12):

You can get **Qty** or other values like min qty by using that method.

```
echo $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

OR Complete Object Data

```
print_r($_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getData());
```

Comment: A much better approach, I can confirm this works in 2.2.1

Comment: and works in 2.2.2 too.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get with this piece​ of code below:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
?>
```

Comment: BTW you shouldn't load it this way anywhere in file, use the same approach using proper design way ( Helper classes or anything like that ). Don't violate SOLID design principles.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful for you-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$product_qty = $product['quantity_and_stock_status']['qty'];
```